# Why doesn't Maps in guava version 21.0 take java.util.function.Function etc as parameters?

Tags: java, java-8, guava, api-design

Guava recently switched to [require java 8](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release21). How come classes like [Maps](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html), don't take java.util.function.Function as parameters instead of com.google.common.base.Function? com.google.common.base.Function extends java.util.function.Function so there shouldn't be any compatibility problems? What's the plan for porting? Is there a version 22.0 coming up with this approach?

Comment: Is it to provide a smooth transition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't that mean that everyone already using guava would have to re-compile their code since some of the methods now have changed? They can't simply upgrade without breaking some code.

It's the other way around. That's the set-up:

```
class GuavaFun extends JavaFunc {}

class JavaFunc {}
```

And you have this declaration:

```
public static void test(GuavaFun f) {

}
```

Calling it like this:

```
test(new JavaFunc());
```

will fail.

If **you could** extend JavaFun and make it:

```
class JavaFunc extends GuavaFun {}
```

then you could pass one or the other to the test method.

**If you have your Functions declared pre java-8 style this will break, but a lambda will not**.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    java.util.function.Function<String, String> f2 = (String b) -> b.toUpperCase();

    test((String a) -> a.toUpperCase());
    test(f2);

}

public static void test(com.google.common.base.Function<String, String> f) {

}
```

The second test call will fail, while the lambda expression will not; because it is still a `@FunctionalInterface`.

Comment: But if they compiled against com.google.common.base.Function, that means that their code will now be using a com.google.common.base.Function that extends java.util.function.Function so when they supply their instance it will be perfectly safe to use as a java.util.function.Function?

Comment: @jontejj The bytecode will reference the method that takes a guava Function as parameter, which wouldn't be there any more if it was changed to j.u.f.Function. And they can't have both versions of the method otherwise it would break the ability to use lambda's (easily).

Comment: So for clients that used java 8 with guava before version 21.0 it makes sense. I think I understand the reasons now :)

Answer (score 4):

From [Guava's discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/guava-discuss/pwqVbXebwAE/DkEfd7knBAAJ):

> We know we want to make changes to those methods, but it's complicated enough we haven't worked out a full plan yet.  Some utilities around Guava's functional interfaces are rendered completely redundant by Java 8 (see e.g. Predicates.instanceOf(Class) versus Class::isInstance), some like Suppliers.memoize seem still useful -- we want to make sure we have a comprehensive plan for what to do with these methods before we start changing everything, and we're not there yet.
>
> You'll definitely start seeing work on these issues in future Guava releases, but for now I think we're leaving those methods be -- though we recommend passing in lambdas to these methods in general, in which case the compiler will just Do The Right Thing.
>
> -- Louis Wasserman

This answers the questions in the following way:

1. **Why doesn't Maps in guava version 21.0 take java.util.function.Function etc as parameters?**

   The impact was too big and the plan wasn't totally worked out when 21.0 hit the shelves.
2. **How come classes like `Maps`, don't take `java.util.function.Function` as parameters instead of `com.google.common.base.Function`?**

   Same as 1.
3. **`com.google.common.base.Function` extends `java.util.function.Function` so there shouldn't be any compatibility problems?**

   (Only partially answered by the quote)
   Yes, there are some of those issues. But to be on the safe side, use the new lambda notation.
4. **What's the plan for porting?**

   The plan is currently being worked out.
5. **Is there a version 22.0 coming up with this approach?**

   (Not covered by the quote) Most likely not. Though I can't say for sure. Check the source code of the current branch of Guava and you'll see it's still using Guava's `Function`.

Comment: that is about *replacing* entirely the guava's function/predicates to java function/predicates. A lambda/method reference will work because guava's interfaces are still `@FunctionalInterface` because they declare a single abstract method.

Comment: There are about five questions in the question post. (At least) Three of them are answered by this answer.